# speedup mysql query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have three tables with about 5k rows each

**USERS** `id, email`

**FLASH2TIMBRES** `id, id_user, photo_name, valid`

**VOTES** `id, id_user, id_photo`

I use this query that makes my site run very slow.

```
SELECT  users.email, 
        flash2timbres.id, 
        flash2timbres.id_user, 
        flash2timbres.photo_name, 
        flash2timbres.time, 
        COUNT(votes.id ) AS nbvotes 
FROM    users, flash2timbres 
        LEFT JOIN votes 
            ON flash2timbres.id = votes.id_photo 
WHERE   valid = 1 AND 
        flash2timbres.id_user = users.id 
GROUP    BY flash2timbres.id 
ORDER BY `flash2timbres`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Can someone help me improve it?

**EDIT**: Indexes are:

```
users.id PRIMARY (Type BTREE) Unique  
flash2timbres.id PRIMARY (Type BTREE) Unique  
votes.id PRIMARY (Type BTREE) Unique
```

Comment: Can you post the table declares please. You probably should have all the non aggregate columns from the SELECT in the GROUP BY  clause.

Comment: Shouldn't you specify a column in "ORDER BY DESC"?

Comment: Yes he should have specified a column there. Does that mean this guy never executed this query and measured the speed? How then can he ask to improve that?

Comment: What are your indexes? Where is your EXPLAIN plan?

Comment: Do you have indexes? Please post information about them too...

Comment: The guy did execute the query and speed is bad. Thanks Elisa. I've edited my post. This the query is just one of the many possible ways I do this inside a function. I use Codeigniter and I pass loads of params depending on my needs, like ORDER BY RAND, DESC, ASC, LIMITS, OFFSETS etc. That's why I had an error, sorry fixed it.

Comment: The problem is probably down to the indexes, hence we need to know what they are (and the table definitions give them) before we can provide any useful help. For example do you have an index on id_photo on the votes table or id_user on the flash2timbres table? For performance ORDER BY RAND() can perform very badly, so if the problem is occasional it might just be that.

Comment: Thanks @Kickstart, I have to use RAND sometimes. Sometimes I need to show three random photos from the galery to promote them on the homepage. runs loads faster now with the indexes. I have a very basic knowledge in database technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, you should take a look at indexing your tables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html. Joins are notoriously slow if not performed on indexed fields, especially when your data sets grow.

Once you've added your indexes, add an EXPLAIN before your query and run it. The result will confirm that the query is now using the new index (in the `key` column).

Comment: Thanks. I guess my database is really basic. It runs so fast now. Before indexes I couldn't even put the EXPLAIN as I got a server timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Add indexes on id_photo on the votes table and also on the id_user column on the flash2timbres table